# COUNTIFS Where second condition can be this or this or that

Tags: excel

Morning All

Trying to work out how to do a countifs where the second condition can be a few different totals. The total should = 2 but I can not get it to work.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

=SUM(COUNTIFS(V14:V30,{"F","B","H1","H2","LT"},T14:T30,U8))